# List design in css using sprites as the "bullet" for the list items

Tags: html, css

So far I managed to design a dialog bubble and wrap three list items in it. The idea is that I want to obtain a list where the bullet (list-style-type) is represented as an image loaded from a sprite. The problem is that the only way to set an image as the "bullet" is by list-style-image, but in that case I cannot use a sprite, only a full image, and I cannot add more HTML tags(this is the template). I saw some hack with :after but I cannot use it as it is already used for the little triangle from the dialog box. Here is my code so far:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 30%;
}

ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.alice {
    max-width: 30%;
    min-height: 30%;
    left: 400px;
    text-align: center;

    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 1em 0 3em;
    border: 5px solid black;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    /*list-style-image cu alice(incarcata din sprite)*/
    /*list-style-image: url("alice-bob.png");*/
}

.alice::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto;
    left: -30px;
    border-width: 15px 30px 15px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: 10px;

    background-image: url("alice-bob.png");

}

.alice::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 9px 21px 9px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent white;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: 16px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: -21px;
}

.bob {
    max-width: 30%;
    min-height: 30%;
    left: 400px;
    text-align: center;

    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 1em 0 3em;
    border: 5px solid black;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    /* css3 */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bob::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
    left: -30px; /* controls horizontal position */
    border-width: 15px 30px 15px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: 10px;
}

.bob::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 9px 21px 9px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #fff;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: 16px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: -21px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="dialog">
    <li class="alice">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
    <li class="bob">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste nat us error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
        totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt
    </li>
    <li class="alice">Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it has to look in the end:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using both the :before + :after pseudo elements for the chat arrow, I use one pseudo for the the chat character and the other pseudo for the chat bubble arrow: https://jsfiddle.net/jx9wsLa7/28/

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: helvetica, verdana, arial;
}
ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    left: 111px;
    margin: 1em 0 3.3em;
    padding: 15px;
    max-width: 33%;
    min-height: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #3D444E;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
ul li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -140px;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    content: "";
}
ul li::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    left: -13px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: -6px 4px 0px black;
    transform: skew(-15deg, -15deg) rotate(45deg);
    content: "";
}
.alice::before {
    background-image: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-avatars-1/512/users-12-4-128.png');
}
.bob::before {
    background-image: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-avatars-1/512/users-10-3-128.png');
}
```

I also moved around some of your CSS so that it is less repetitive and easier to make adjustments.

I found the characters here: https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=girl+guy

ALSO, might look better with thinner border if you change 3 lines like so: https://jsfiddle.net/jx9wsLa7/32/

```
ul li {
    border: 2px solid #3D444E;
}
ul li::after {
    left: -14px;
    box-shadow: -2.5px 1.5px 0px #3D444E;
}
```

Another way of improving the look of this chat bubble would be to just go without the borders and choose a solid colour, like in this example: https://codepen.io/adevade/pen/iCEus

Comment: @Bogdan Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there any way to style my css code for the list item in order to extend horizontally as much as possible and only than vertically for long text?

Comment: so that it is responsive? is this what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/jx9wsLa7/39/

Comment: Actually I wanted the list item to take as much space as needed regarding its content, but I managed to solve the problem by using display: table on each list item. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect, Thanks !!